# Need help centering a form

Tags: html, css, forms, input, alignment

Well I have been searching over the last hour in attempt to center a form for a name, and well I am struggling till this point so decided to ask here. Yes I have searched this place to..

My [HTML](http://pastie.org/8345948):

```html
<div id="main" class="main">
    <table border="0" class="container1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    <img src="images/doesitfit.png" />
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0">
        <div class="container2">
            <input type="text" value="Enter Your First Name" id="form" onblur="javascript:if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Your First Name';" onclick="javascript:if(this.value=='Enter Your First Name')this.value='';"></input>
        </div>
    </table>
</div>
```

My [CSS](http://pastie.org/8345950):

```css
.main {
    background-color: rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.8);
    width: 800px;
    height: 550px;
    border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 10em;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container1 {
    table-layout: fixed;
    height:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 802px;
    border-color:#ff0000;
    border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 10em;
    color:white;
    margin: auto;
}
.container2 {
}
#form {
    font-size: 19px;
    border: 0px solid;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    height:28px;
    width:295px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Also, I plan to add a few more forms (input), such as Email, and phone number.

Thanks very much SOF, hoping to get some help finally.

Comment: If you have a question about some code you wrote, then provide the code *here* (preferably as a reduced test case) don't link to an external site. You code has a number of errors that would be picked up if you used [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: The table shouldn't contain the div element to be its direct child: `<table><div></div></table>`= this is invalid. Fix it with this: `<table><tr><td><div></div></td></tr></table>` Also you can use the placeholder attribute for your input: `<input type="text" id="form" placeholder="Enter Your First Name"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a CodePen to showcase how you can center the input. (http://codepen.io/kevingimbel/pen/BKruj)

The main probleme here is that `margin: 0 auto;` wont't work until the Input is set to `display:block;` - also I think you shouldn't use `<table>` for layouts - use `<div>`.

Anyway I also commented the CSS inside the Pen. If you need more help post it, I'll watch this thread for some time. 
Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks a ton, guess I read quite a bit of other posts wrong with the display:block; I'd read everything as display:inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
form {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: you dont seem to have a form element in your html

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your input in form element and lose the # symbol before form in CSS

```
<form>
  <input type="text" value="Enter Your First Name" onblur="javascript:if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Your First Name';" onclick="javascript:if(this.value=='Enter Your First Name')this.value='';">></input>
</form>


form {
  font-size: 19px;
  border: 0 solid;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  height: 28px;
  width: 295px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or if you want to preserve input ID form

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Your First Name" id="form" onblur="javascript:if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Your First Name';" onclick="javascript:if(this.value=='Enter Your First Name')this.value='';">></input>


#form {
  display: block;
  font-size: 19px;
  border: 0 solid;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  height: 28px;
  width: 295px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```